# How can I sort a nested list accordign to each element in nested lists

Tags: python, django, sorting, nested-lists

I have a model Page which stores an optional parent page (instance of itself). In my views I made a function which will return a nested list of all pages and their parents.

For example, my page architecture is

```
CCC
  AAA
    DDD
    KKK
      EEE
ZZZ
  BBB
```

So DDD has the parent page AAA, which has it's own parent page CCC. The CCC is top page and has no parent page.

The function will first get a queryset of all instances of Pages and sort them alphabetically. Then it will proceed to recursively generate a "full parent architecture" list, where each element on that list is another list of all parent pages, including the page itself. From the example above if we take a slice of list for page DDD, it would return [CCC, AAA, DDD].

My function currently returns a list like this for the above stated example:

```
[ 
  [CCC, AAA],
  [ZZZ, BBB],
  [CCC],
  [CCC, AAA, DDD],
  [CCC, AAA, KKK, EEE],
  [CCC, AAA, KKK],
  [ZZZ],
]
```

As you can see from the that list, all elements are sorted alphabetically according to the last element on that list. Now I want to display all those parent pages on my front end to basically look like a sitemap and show the proper parent architecture of all Pages on my site that is sorted alphabetically according to each element in each nested list. The end result would be:

```
[ 
  [CCC],
  [CCC, AAA],
  [CCC, AAA, DDD],
  [CCC, AAA, KKK],
  [CCC, AAA, KKK, EEE],
  [ZZZ],
  [ZZZ, BBB],
]
```

To put it simple, I want to go through each first element on each list and sort it alphabetically, then each second element and sort them as well, then third, then forth, and so on. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
To avoid confusion here's my view:

```
def page_list(request):


    # Fetch all pages and sort them alphabetically
    queryset = Page.objects.all().order_by("title")
    output = []

    # Generate list of pages and their parents
    for page in queryset:
        output.append(get_list_of_parents(page))

    context = {
        "title": "Page List",
        "page_list": output,
    }

    return render(request, template + '/page_list.html', context)

# Get an array of all parent instances of a Page model
def get_list_of_parents(page, list=None):

    current_page = page 
    parent_list = []    

    if list is not None:
        parent_list = list

    parent_list.append(current_page)

    if current_page.parent is not None:
        parent_list = get_list_of_parents(current_page.parent, parent_list)
    else:
        # if this is the last parent page, reverse the order of list to display list in form of parent path to child
        parent_list.reverse()

    return parent_list
```

Comment: Is there an error in the end result? Do you mean: `[CCC, AAA, DDD],
  [CCC, AAA, KKK], [CCC, AAA, KKK, EEE],` instead?

Comment: Traverse your tree using Depth-first search algorithm, storing each step in a list.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort a sub-list of lists alphabetically?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE yes that's a typo, i'll edit in a second

Comment: @Mr.goosberry no, each nested list is sorted properly. For each of those list, last element is final child, and all previous elements are parents, so for page DDD it displays [parentOfParenOfDDD, parentOfDDD, DDD]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of helper functions in itertools and do your sorting with a simple and highly efficient one-line comparison function.

```
>>> import pprint
>>> from itertools import dropwhile, izip_longest
>>> pages = [['CCC', 'AAA'],
...          ['ZZZ', 'BBB'],
...          ['CCC'],
...          ['CCC', 'AAA', 'DDD'],
...          ['CCC', 'AAA', 'DDD', 'EEE'],
...          ['CCC', 'AAA', 'KKK'],
...          ['ZZZ']]
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(pages, cmp=lambda a, b: cmp(*next(dropwhile(lambda x: not cmp(x[0], x[1]), izip_longest(a, b))))))
[['CCC'],
 ['CCC', 'AAA'],
 ['CCC', 'AAA', 'DDD'],
 ['CCC', 'AAA', 'DDD', 'EEE'],
 ['CCC', 'AAA', 'KKK'],
 ['ZZZ'],
 ['ZZZ', 'BBB']]
>>>
```

This works not only for strings, but also Page instances, as long as they are comparable, i.e. that you have defined your `__cmp__` method in your Page class.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please feel free to comment on why this is not a good solution and/or provide a even better answer. Thank you.

Comment: Ok gonna test this now. Atm I'm getting a typerror 'cmp' is an invalid keyword argument for this function, which I guess is the lack of `__cmp__` from page model. Let me look around to see if i can make it

Comment: I can show you how to define your `__cmp__` method if you can show us how your Page model is defined.

Comment: I just saw the edit in your question and can now assume that your pages are compared to by their titles, in which case your `__cmp__` can be defined as:

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.title, other.title)

Comment: I added the `def __cmp__(self, other):  return cmp(self.title, other.title) ` to the model, although they can be compared with id or slug. However the error persists: `TypeError at /dashboard/pages/custom 'cmp' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` on the line `test = sorted(output, cmp=lambda a, b: cmp(*next(dropwhile(lambda x: not cmp(x[0], x[1]), izip_longest(a, b)))))`

Comment: You may have a very old version of python that doesn't support cmp as a keyword argument to the built-in sorted function. Try using the sort method of list instead, i.e. pages.sort(cmp=lambda a, b: cmp(*next(dropwhile(lambda x: not cmp(x[0], x[1]), izip_longest(a, b)))))

Comment: By the way, cmp(x[0], x[1]) can be shortened with cmp(*x), i.e. pages.sort(cmp=lambda a, b: cmp(*next(dropwhile(lambda x: not cmp(*x), izip_longest(a, b)))))

Comment: Py version 3.5.2 and django 1.10.1, pretty up to date as far as versions go. On that note I had to import zip_longest instead, as izip_longest is not in py 3.X+. I continue to get the same error with sort(). In the meantime I'm working on making the list into a 2D array and then just manipulate the rows to sort them in correct order. Although I was hoping for something short like your line, whatever works I guess. Thank you for your time, I'll probably look into cmp later, right now I just want to have a basic site app up and running.

Comment: Ahh so you're using python 3, while I'm still using python 2! In python 3, zip_longest is equivalent to izip_longest of python 2, and instead of cmp=..., use key=functools.cmp_to_key... i.e., import functools ... sorted(pages, key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: cmp(*next(dropwhile(lambda x: not cmp(*x), zip_longest(a, b))))))

Comment: Finally got it working. Had some problems with cmp, seems it's gone in py3, so I had to make cmp func to compare titles. You should update the your original replay with solution.

Comment: As for downvotes, no use in complaining. It's petty behavior if you downvote without elaborating why. It just makes people less inclined to use this site and I get a feeling it wasn't a legitimate downvote either. That's why I use SO as the last resort, when I can't find answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tree of Pages:

I define this simple tree structure:

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, name, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children or []

    def display(self, indent=""):
        child_repr = [child.display(indent=indent + "  ") for child in self.children]
        return indent + self.name + "\n" + "".join(child_repr)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display()
```

The `display` and `__str__` methods are used for printing.

I can build your tree as a list of Pages:

```
tree = [
    Page("CCC", [
        Page("AAA", [
            Page("DDD"),
            Page("KKK", [
                Page("EEE")])])]),
    Page("ZZZ", [
        Page("BBB")])]
```

I can display the structure like this:

```
for item in tree:
    print(item)
```

I get:

```
CCC
  AAA
    DDD
    KKK
      EEE

ZZZ
  BBB
```

To traverse the tree, I define the following method:

```
    def traverse(self, result, stack=None):
        stack = stack or []
        stack.append(self.name)
        result.append(list(stack))
        for child in self.children:
            child.traverse(result, stack)
        stack.pop()
```

Where `result` is the list to fill.

Usage:

```
result = []
for item in tree:
    item.traverse(result)

import pprint

pprint.pprint(result)
```

I'll get:

```
[['CCC'],
 ['CCC', 'AAA'],
 ['CCC', 'AAA', 'DDD'],
 ['CCC', 'AAA', 'KKK'],
 ['CCC', 'AAA', 'KKK', 'EEE'],
 ['ZZZ'],
 ['ZZZ', 'BBB']]
```

Great!

Comment: I'm fairly new to python and django, but from what I understand you're suggesting that I change my page model so it stores list of children instead of single parent? If so that's not an option. Publishers would have to save a page, then edit other page to add new one as child. The thing is, if publishers are not owners of the parent page, they will not be able to edit it. Only publishers who created the page are associated with it and only they can edit/delete the page. Other publishers can view it, and set it as a parent page, but not change the parent instance if they're not original publish

Comment: PS, since you replied, I updated my original post and included the two functions in that list all the pages and create nested lists of all pages and their parents.

Comment: I don't know your database model, but usually, when you have a parent/ children relationship, the parent maintains a list of children and each child has a reference to its parent. It's up to the ORM to handle this relationship for you. So, usually it's not a problem.